# Technical English for HTTP

Tags: word-request, terminology

This is a simple question but regarding a little bit more "Technical" english. It has been years since I have worked with HTTP (web) so I have forgotten.

In a client-server system you can "Post" and "Get" information to and from a Server. One is from client to server, the other from server to client.

When you request information from the server (with GET) you call that a "request"

How do you call when you send information to the server (with POST)? I can't recall the correct word...

---

EDIT:
Just in case, rather than a question about HTTP (which should go to So or sites like this) this is a question centered on finding a english word that sounds natural for english speakers. The theme is HTTP, yes, but the point is I am translating a document in japanese to english which uses "Youkyu" (request) for GET and "Tsuchi"(notification, Report) for POST.

I am going for "Submission". How about that? Does it sound correct?

Comment: Both GET and POST are requests, they're just different types of requests. Do you have a particular sentence you're trying to construct?

Comment: Yes, well I am traslating a document from japanese. Here the words "youkyuu"(request) is used for GET and for POST "Tsuchi" is used. Tsuchi means something like "notification, report" etc. But I don't think they are right to describe an operation that uses POST.

Comment: "One is from client to server, the other from server to client." implies you might mean Request and Response, but that's a different distinction from GET and POST (which are both Requests) could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

*POST and GET are two HTTP request methods.* A google search returned me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477406/38038399) post in Stack Overflow as the first result.

> POST and GET are two HTTP request methods. GET is usually intended to retrieve some data, and is expected to be idempotent (repeating the query does not have any side-effects) and can only send limited amounts of parameter data to the server. GET requests are often cached by default by some browsers if you are not careful.
>
> POST is intended for changing the server state. It carries more data, and repeating the query is allowed (and often expected) to have side-effects such as creating two messages instead of one.

Comment: Alright. So I guess I can use "Retrieval" instead of Request for my translation of "Youkyu"(literally request in japanese). How about using "Submission" when talking about POST operations? Does it sound natural for english speakers?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, POST is a 'request' (as is everything in HTTP) but most commonly I see the word itself used, e.g. "POSTing data"  or  "POSTed data"  or  "POST this to the server".

Often, though, the actual mechanism is ignored, so an author might talk about "form submission" without mentioning POST, since it can be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

As a computer programmer, I would like to suggest usage of:

> Submitted Request

Because with `GET` request actually you are preparing a form for a client with some predefined options to be submitted by the client!

So for a returning `POST` request you can easily say **"submitted request"**.